# Send data from specific class within looped jinja classes to modal

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to send specific data from flask route to another template or more specifically a modal.
I want to be able to select one of the dynamically create divs from the data
passed from flask by pressing the 'details' button and send its associated data e.g.(location name) to a modal that pops up with the table of the data presented. The problem is I can't select any specific data/class from looped flask data to send back to template or more I don't know how to.

Not sure if I need JS or Jquery to select the location name at top of div upon pressing button within associated div so then I can then send that data to template for it to be queried in whatever way so I could then go about sending. Please help if possible.

This is what is viewed from user. This is the dynamic content that is created between each distinct location number within db:

[image]

Please point me in the right direction in upon pressing the details button
-Selecting associated data from from element clicked on

This is an example of the html. The html I have written is too long to paste but here is the general idea. I need to be able to access the location name or x did upon pressing the details button and send this to the template or to the modal.

```
{% for totals, x, answered, no_answer in location %}
<div class='test'>
    <div>location {{x.did}}<div>
    <div>{{totals}}</div>
    <div>{{answered}}</div>
    <div> {{no_answer}} </div>
</div>
```

-Then sending this data to a modal that pops upon pressing 'Details' button.

This is the Route that had queried data to send to template

```
 @app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
    def reports():
    form = ReportConfig()
    location = Cdr.query.with_entities(Cdr.did).distinct().all()

    totals = []
    answered = []
    no_answer = []

    for x in location:
        test = str(x.did)
        totalcalls = connection.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(calldate) FROM cdr WHERE did='{test}'")
        answered_count = connection.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(calldate) FROM cdr WHERE did='{test}' AND disposition='ANSWERED'")
        no = connection.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(calldate) FROM cdr WHERE did='{test}' AND disposition='NO ANSWER'")

        answer_num = [row[0] for row in answered_count]
        print(answer_num[0])

        nono = [row[0] for row in no]
        print(nono[0])

        total = [row[0] for row in totalcalls]
        print(total[0])

        totals.append(total[0])
        answered.append(answer_num[0])
        no_answer.append(nono[0])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('You have validated mane')
        form = ReportConfig()
        start_date = request.form['start_date']
        end_date = request.form['end_date']
        location = Cdr.query.with_entities(Cdr.did).distinct().all()    

        totals = []
        answered = []       
        no_answer = []

        for x in location:
            test = str(x.did)
            totalcalls = connection.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(calldate) FROM cdr WHERE did='{test}' and calldate between '{start_date} 08:00:00' and '{end_date} 08:00:00'")
            answered_count = connection.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(calldate) FROM cdr WHERE did='{test}' AND disposition='ANSWERED' AND calldate between '{start_date} 08:00:00' and '{end_date} 08:00:00'")
            no = connection.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(calldate) FROM cdr WHERE did='{test}' AND disposition='NO ANSWER' AND calldate between '{start_date} 08:00:00' and '{end_date} 08:00:00'")

            answer_num = [row[0] for row in answered_count]
            print(answer_num[0])

            nono = [row[0] for row in no]
            print(nono[0])

            total = [row[0] for row in totalcalls]
            print(total[0])

            totals.append(total[0])
            answered.append(answer_num[0])
            no_answer.append(nono[0])
            print(start_date, end_date)
        return render_template('reports.html', form=form, location=zip(totals, location, answered, no_answer))
    return render_template('reports.html', title='Home', form=form, location=zip(totals, location, answered, no_answer))
```